# How can I bind a mouseover using jQuery after the DOM has loaded?

Tags: jquery, css

Note: I am just learning jQuery, so if this can be done more efficiently, please do share.

I am coding a follow/unfollow feature. The portion where the user follows another user works (see first snippet below), but now I want to change "Following" to say, "Unfollow" when the user hovers/mouseovers "Following".

The code to "Follow" is here (it works):

```
$(document).on('click','a.follow-user',function () {
    event.preventDefault();
    var action = $(this).attr("action");
    var userid = $(this).attr("userid");
    var follower_userid = $(this).attr("follower_userid");

    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/follow-user.php",
            data: "action=" + action + "&userid=" + userid + "&follower_userid=" + follower_userid,
            success: function(data) {
                if (data == "FOLLOWED") {
                    $(".follow-user").html("Following");
                    $(".follow-user").attr({"action" : "0"});
                    $(".follow-user").removeClass("follow-user").addClass("following-user");
                } else {
                    $(".follow-user").removeClass(".follow-user").addClass("icon-warning-sign");
                }
            }
    });
});
```

and the code for when the mouse is over the "Following" text is here (it doesn't work - no errors):

```
$(".following-user").on("mouseover", function () {
    $(this).html("Unfollow")
    $(this).attr({"action" : "1"});

    }).mouseout(function() {

    $(this).html("Following")
    $(this).attr({"action" : "0"});
});
```

Comment: provide the html please

Comment: Where is `.following-user`?

Comment: .following-user is part of .addClass("following-user") in the first snippet ...it replaces .follow-user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need this:

```
$(document).on( 'mouseover', '.following-user', function() {
```

Comment: this worked ...thanks. I had tried similar with the class where 'document' is, but it didn't work that way. Also, your answer and other were correct but I gave the correct answer to you because it was posted a minute earlier than the next right answer.

Answer (score 0):

try delgating the `following-user` to document or closest static parent

```
$(document).on("mouseover", ".following-user",function () {
```

Answer (score 0):

Bind your event handlers using event delegation.

```
$(document).on({
  mouseover: function () {
    $(this).html("Unfollow").attr({
      "action": "1"
    });
  },
  mouseout: function () {
    $(this).html("Following").attr({
      "action": "0"
    });
  }
}, ".following-user");
```

Especially since you are altering the HTML of them.